# Passing a #define parameters to class

Tags: c, header-files

I have main function which is in one folder and there is one class with some useful functions in another folder. In the main function I have this code:

```
#include "UsefulFunctions.h" 
#define PRINTINGLINE 0
#if PRINTINGLINE == 1
    #define debug(x) Serial.print(x)
    #define debugln(x) Serial.println(x)
#else
    #define debug(x)
   #define debugln(x)
#endif
```

I use this so i can save some processor time and memory, and i can easy turn on and off by change one value. But this is in main how can i use this in the UsefulFucntions without make double code and changes on two places?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Put the defines in a header and include it where you want to use it.

Comment: "there is one *class* with some useful functions", well, are you sure the `c` is the right tag here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Put the defines in a header and include it where you want to use it. –@Retired Ninja`

Thanks , this did the job .
Thanks for everyone who shared their opinion.

W1zz1 :)

Can be Locked .

Answer (score 2):

```
#ifndef USEFULFUNCTIONS_H
#define USEFULFUNCTIONS_H

#define PRINTINGLINE 0
#if PRINTINGLINE == 1
    #define debug(x) Serial.print(x)
    #define debugln(x) Serial.println(x)
#else
    #define debug(x)
    #define debugln(x)
#endif

#endif /* USEFULFUNCTIONS_H */
```

Editing the file "UsefulFunctions.h " like that; using the #ifndef